# In C#, is "SELECT TOP 0 * FROM (/* ... */) s" used in conjuction with ADO.NET a good way to determine the column information in a SELECT statement?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a SQL SELECT statement which will not be known until runtime, which could contain JOIN's and inner selects.  I need to determine the names and data types of each of the columns of the returned result of the statment from within C#.  I am inclined to do something like:

```
string orginalSelectStatement = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

string selectStatement = string.Format("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM ({0}) s", orginalSelectStatement);
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"MyConnectionString");
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectStatement, connection);

DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);

foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}; Type: {1}", column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
}
```

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?  By "better" I mean either a less resource-intensive way of accomplishing the same task or a more sure way of accomplishing the same task (i.e. for all I know the code snippet I just gave will fail in some situations).

**SOLUTION**:
First of all, my `TOP 0` hack is bad, namely for something like this:

`SELECT TOP 0 * FROM (SELECT 0 AS A, 1 AS A) S`

In other words, in a sub-select, if two things are aliased to the same name, that throws an error.  So it is out of the picture.  However, for completeness sake, I went ahead and tested it, along with the two proposed solutions:  `SET FMTONLY ON` and `GetSchemaTable`.

Here are the results (in milliseconds for 1,000 queries, each):

> Schema Time: 3130
>
> TOP 0 Time: 2808
>
> FMTONLY ON Time: 2937

**My recommendation would be `GetSchemaTable`** since it's more likely to be future-proofed by a removal of the `SET FMTONLY ON` as valid SQL and it solves the aliasing problem, even though it is slightly slower.  **However, if you "know" that duplicate column names will never be an issue, then `TOP 0` is faster than `GetSchemaTable`** and is more future-proofed than `SET FMTONLY ON`.

Here is my experimental code:

```
int schemaTime = 0;
int topTime = 0;
int fmtOnTime = 0;

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"MyConnectionString");
connection.Open();

SqlCommand schemaCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable", connection);
SqlCommand topCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable) S", connection);
SqlCommand fmtOnCommand = new SqlCommand("SET FMTONLY ON; SELECT * FROM MyTable", connection);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        using (SqlDataReader reader = schemaCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
        {
            DataTable table = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        }
        DateTime stop = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan span = stop - start;
        schemaTime += span.Milliseconds;
    }

    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(topCommand);
        adapter.Fill(table);

        DateTime stop = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan span = stop - start;
        topTime += span.Milliseconds;
    }

    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(fmtOnCommand);
        adapter.Fill(table);

        DateTime stop = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan span = stop - start;
        fmtOnTime += span.Milliseconds;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Schema Time: " + schemaTime);
Console.WriteLine("TOP 0 Time: " + topTime);
Console.WriteLine("FMTONLY ON Time: " + fmtOnTime);

connection.Close();
```

Comment: Not sure about TOP 0, I will try with WHERE 1=0, but the best is if you know the primary key and put a WHERE PK=an_impossible_value

Comment: I thought I remember reading once that SQL Server optimizes TOP 1 queries, so I figured it may do that for TOP 0 queries, as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [GetSchemaTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable.aspx) to do what you want.

There is an example of how to use it [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310107).

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  Why would I use this over what I am currently doing, or Icarus' SET FMTONLY ON approach?

Comment: I don't know that there's a specific benefit using GetSchemaTable (in fact, that method may be doing something similar to what the other answerers suggested). It's just one way of doing it. However, I'd _assume_ that it'd work regardless of the database connection, so that's one possible benefit.

Comment: I just ran a SQL profile on SQL Server 2008 on the GetSchemaTable method and here's what it did: `SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NO_BROWSETABLE ON; SELECT * FROM [MyTable] SET NO_BROWSETABLE OFF;`  I am still looking into `NO_BROWSETABLE` to see what it does.

Answer (score 2):

If using SQL Server, I would try using [SET FMTONLY ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

> Returns only metadata to the client. Can be used to test the format of
>   the response without **actually running the query.**

Apparently on SQL Server 2012, there's a better way. All is specified in the linked MSDN article.

BTW, this technique is what LINQ To SQL uses internally to determine the result set returned by a stored procedure, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! If this is what LINQ To SQL uses, then I am inclined to think this may be the most efficient method.  Could you (briefly) give any explanation of this compares to what I'm doing or the GetSchemaTable approach?

Comment: @WordsLikeJared I just read a link regarding NO_BROWSETABLE (I didn't know about this option) but it seems that it actually executes the statement. FMTONLY ON will not execute the statement; therefore, I would assume is far more efficient.

Comment: It (`SET FMTONLY ON`) by itself actually seemed to perform slower than `GetSchemaTable`, consistently, in my experiments, which, along with the latter being more future proofed, more likely, is the reason I chose it as the answer to my question and not yours.  You did get an up-vote, of course, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is always a bit of a minefield, but you could the SET FMTONLY ON on your query - this means the query will only return Metadata, the same as if no results were returned.  So:

```
string selectStatement = string.Format("SET FMTONLY ON; {0}", orginalSelectStatement);
```

Alternatively, if you aren't tied to ADO, could you not go down the [Linq-to-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399398.aspx) route and generate a data context which will map out all of your database schemas in to code and their relevant types?  You could also have a look at some of the Micro ORMs out there, such as [Dapper.Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

There are plenty of other ORMs out there too.